# Unable to use picasso as well as jsoup in a android gradle project

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to parse images from MangaRock with JSoup and Picasso in an android app. When adding Picasso as a dependency, gradle refuses to compile, saying that:

```
All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0, 27.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0
```

Here is my `build.gradle`

```java
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.12.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this as by `build.gradle` instead. The major difference is the bump to sdk version 28 for everything.

```java
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.12.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
}
```